# $x+x^2+x^3=x^4+x^5+x^6$ implies $x^4=x$ in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(A,+,.)$ be a ring s.t. $x+x^2+x^3=x^4+x^5+x^6$  for all $x  \in A$. Prove that $x^4=x$ for all $x$ in $A$. Can somebody give me some tips, please?

Comment: Is the ring commutative?  Does it necessarily have a multiplicative identity?

Comment: Plug in $x=-1$ to find that $2=0$ in $A$. Rearrange to get $$(x+x^2+x^3)(1-x^3)=0,$$ for all $x$, where $1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)$. So $$x(1+x)(1+x+x^2)^2=0.$$

Comment: @Servaes It should be an answer.

Comment: And how can you get to $x^4$ ?

Comment: It depends. Is $A$ assumed to be unital? Commutative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a variant of the solution by @Servaes that seems simpler to me:

Plugging $x=-1$ gives $2=0$ in $A$.

Therefore, $x+x^2+x^3=x^4+x^5+x^6$ is the same as $x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6=0$.

Multiplying that by $x-1$ gives $x^7-x=0$ and so $x^8-x^2=0$.

Now $x^8-x^2=(x^4-x)^2$.

Let $z=x^4-x$. Then $z^2=0$ and $z+z^2+z^3=z^4+z^5+z^6$ imply $z=0$, and so $x^4=x$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1:** Plugging in $x=-1$ shows that $2=0$ in $A$.

**Hint 2:** The given equation can be rearranged to get

> $$(x+x^2+x^3)(1-x^3)=0,$$
>  or equivalently $(x^4-x)(1+x+x^2)=0$. 
>  Multiplying through by $x-x^2$ shows that
>  $$(x^4-x)^2=0.$$

Comment: All these answers say plug in $x = *$ etc. Is x a variable? If it means go mod say for example $x - (-1)$ the relation will hold in the quotient ring.

Comment: @R.C.Cowsik The question states that the identity holds *for all* $x\in A$. Assuming that $A$ is a unital ring, it contains an element $-1$, and so the relation holds for $-1$ in particular.